# I want to move my SKLabelNode object down to up and up to down alternatively

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have designed a `SKLabelNode` object. I wanna to let it move start from down to up and then up to down whenever I touch the `SKLabelNode` object. First it will move from down to up and then it is required to move from up to down. Here is the code.. Anyone can help !

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    SKNode * helloNode=[self childNodeWithName:@"helloNode"];
    if ([helloNode.name isEqualToString:@"helloNode"])
    {
        helloNode.name = @"";
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX: 0 y: 100.0 duration: 0.5];

        SKAction *pause = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
        SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration: 0.25];
        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.25];

        SKAction *moveSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, pause, fadeAway,fadeIn]];
        [helloNode runAction: moveSequence];
    }
    else
    {
        helloNode.name=@"helloNode";
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX: 0 y: 50.0 duration: 0.5];
        SKAction *pause = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
        SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration: 0.25];
        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.25];


        SKAction *moveSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, pause,        fadeAway,fadeIn]];
        [helloNode runAction: moveSequence];

    }
}
```

Comment: SKAction *actionMoveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:20 duration:0.5];

SKAction *actionMoveDown = [actionMoveUp reversedAction];

SKAction *actionMoveUpDown = [SKAction sequence:@[actionMoveUp, actionMoveDown]];

SKAction *actionMoveDownRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionMoveUpDown]; 

[bottomPipe runAction:actionMoveDownRepeat];
[topPipe runAction:actionMoveDownRepeat];

Comment: do no post code like that in comments, edit your question